# How to clear specific block cache in magento2 based on third party api response?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I want to clear category page cache when third party does not return any response and it should be just one time when response 200 i have to clear category page cache again.How to clear specific block cache in magento2 based on third party api response?